# sqlite3_open cannot open file at line

Tags: c++, ios, swift, sqlite

I'm making a ios application using swift with c++ sqlite database. My problem is when I run the code in xcode, I get an error when trying to open the database in c++ file.
[logging-persist] cannot open file at line 42263 of [95fbac39ba]

I tried to get the correct file path like how we would use sqlite in swift and just copied and pasted that path to c++ file but it didn't work. The filepath I got was /Users/racelab/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1B9AB8BA-C000-42CC-8588-211E0928722F/data/Containers/Data/Application/F4C2A19E-10C5-4474-8DFD-D4105C859A19/Documents/buildings.db

```
double Database::getLatitude(const char* nameOfBuilding){
int exit = 0;

exit = sqlite3_open("buildings.db", &db);
```

I expect to get the correct filepath so that I can open sqlite3 database.

Comment: Is this a swift or c++ question? It looks like your database is in the users Document folder.

Comment: I developed an ios app using swift on xcode but my class requires that we need to have some c++ part in it so we decided to make the database in c++ and the app will just access the database to pull information. I have the building.db, the database file in the same folder as other swift files and also added the file in xcode project.

Comment: @JoonLee Did you find solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass Database path instead of name

```
exit = sqlite3_open(DB_PATH, &db);
```

Use [fileSystemRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1414559-filesystemrepresentation) to convert string path to `char*`

```
[strPath fileSystemRepresentation];
```

Comment: How do i find the DB_PATH in c++ file?